# Using a wildcard character in linux-ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

Make the spreadsheets directory your working directory. Make copies of the datainfo file in the spreadsheets directory, so that one copy is named myinfo and one is named datadata. Next, use a wildcard character to list all files that start with “data.” Use a wildcard character to list all files that end

I have two file inside of my spreadsheets directory called  myinfo and datadata.

terminal:  /home/****/Documents/spreadsheets/

OK, how to use a wildcard character to list all files that start with data

Answer (score 1):

You can just use **wildcard** with `ls`, like:

```
ls data*
ls /home/****/Documents/spreadsheets/data*
```

Comment: If you are not going to provide any explanation, this would make a good *comment* (and you would still have `462` characters of comment space left.)

Comment: @chengpohi thank for responding, are saying once i am in my spreadsheets folder from my terminal, I only need to type in cd data* to unlock the wildcard characters

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin are you talking to me

Comment: No, this was guidance to the answerer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Thanks call out.

Comment: @chengpohi ok i got it

Comment: Much better, always try and make sure you provide enough explanation that you are sure any new user understands. I'll do a counter example that probably provides more than needed, but somewhere between the two should be just right.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you will want to look at the manual page under:

> ```
> Pathname Expansion / Pattern Matching
>
> *   Matches any string, including the null string. When the globstar shell
>     option is enabled, and * is used in a pathname expansion context, two 
>     adjacent *s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or 
>     more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a /, two adjacent 
>     *s will match only directories and subdirectories.
> ```

When you want to match zero or more characters in a filename, you can use *filename globbing*. The `'*'`, in your case, when included at the end of `data` can be used to match any files in the directory that begin with `data` (e.g. `data_first`, `datadata`, but not `mydata`). For example, give the following `tstdir` with subdirectories (`d1-4`):

```
tstdir
├── d1
│   ├── d1_f1
│   ├── d1_f2
│   └── d1_f3
├── d2
│   ├── d2_f1
│   ├── d2_f2
│   └── d2_f3
├── d3
│   ├── d3_f1
│   ├── d3_f2
│   └── d3_f3
├── d4
│   ├── f1_d4
│   ├── f2_d4
│   └── f3_d4
├── f1
├── f2
├── f3
├── m1
├── m2
└── m3
```

To match all files under `tstdir` beginning with `f`, you would use:

```
$ ls -1 tstdir/f*
tstdir/f1
tstdir/f2
tstdir/f3
```

To match all files beginning with `f` within the subdirectories, you would need a way to match each of the subdirectories and also match the files within them beginning with `f`. You could accomplish that with two adjacent `*'s` (e.g. `**`) in the path itsef, e.g.

```
$ ls -1 tstdir/**/f*
tstdir/d4/f1_d4
tstdir/d4/f2_d4
tstdir/d4/f3_d4
```

To match only files in the subdirectories containing `f1`, you could do:

```
$ ls -1 tstdir/**/*f1*
tstdir/d1/d1_f1
tstdir/d2/d2_f1
tstdir/d3/d3_f1
tstdir/d4/f1_d4
```

The counter part to `'*'` for matching only a single-character is `'?'`. To match any of a set of characters, you also have the *character class* available `[...]` where any of the characters specified between the brackets are matched (or not matched in case of `[^...]`, where the circumflex is the first character of the class) For example to match only *files* ending in '2' in the current directory, excluding directories that start with `d`, you could do:

```
$ ls -1 tstdir/[^d]2
tstdir/f2
tstdir/m2
```

or equivalently:

```
$ ls -1 tstdir/[mf]2
tstdir/f2
tstdir/m2
```

Hopefully this will get you started in pattern (wildcard) matching.